# SharePoint: Problem Exporting Versioned List to Excel

Tags: sharepoint, excel, export

I have a list in SharePoint that has versioning turned on. This list contains a multiline text column that stores notes about the list item. The "Export to Excel" function works and produces a spreadsheet of all the list items however, each list item only contains the most recent entry in the notes column. I'd like this export to contain the full history of all the notes in the export.

Does anyone know of a solution for this problem?

Thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Notes multi-line text field has "Append Changes to Existing Text" set to Yes. If you want the out of the box export to excel function to export all of the text, this value must be set to No.

When this is Yes, each change is stored in each list item's version, so when you export to excel it is only the most recent version.